# Select a sentence with rangy.expand()

Tags: javascript, expand, rangy, sentence

I would like to use **rangy** (https://github.com/timdown/rangy) to select the current sentence based on my cursor location. This seems hypothetically possible by declaring the `wordRegex` to gather an entire sentence in the expand options, but I can't seem to get it to work.

My code looks like this:

```
var sentenceOptions;
var r = rangy.getSelection()
sentenceOptions = {
    wordOptions: {
    wordRegex: /\S.+?([\.!?]+(?=\s+|[\{\}\[\]\(\)]+|$)|$)/g, // This should select a sentence
    includeTrailingSpace: true
  },
  characterOptions: {
    boundaryRange: cursor.constructor.limitToCtxRange()
  },
  trim: false
};

r.expand('word', sentenceOptions);
```

This code works correctly for getting the current *word* (when the regex is adjusted accordingly), but does not work for a *sentence*. I have also verified that this regular expression works correctly. Does anyone have any strategies for selecting an entire sentence?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/timdown/rangy/issues/392

Comment: I have...I was hoping there was a way to work around this and create that functionality myself.